# netcat keeps timing out on http get requests

Tags: http, netcat

I'm learning how to use netcat to create my own http get requests and am now trying to apply my knowledge. To this end I've tried the following:

```
nc -v www.ferrari.com 80 
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.ferrari.com
```

When I do press enter after typing the host, I wait a while and it terminates without receiving a response. Could it be the syntax I'm using being obsolete or is there something wrong with my connection.

Comment: After typing header, press ENTER *twice*.

Comment: HTTP message: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html. You need two `CRLF` pairs so two `ENTER`s.